# Column not found in MigrateSourceCSV

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, migration

I have to import a csv in my project, And I Receive this error

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'map.sourceid8' in 'where clause', in mywork/includes/database/database.inc:2171
```

I find the name of my field in my Content Type, and the name is `field_foo`

then I do

```
$this->map = new MigrateSQLMap(
  $this->machineName,

  array(
    ....
    'field_foo' => array(
      'type' => 'varchar',
      'length' => 255,
      'not null' => FALSE,
      'description' => 'field_foo',
    )
  ),
  MigrateDestinationNode::getKeySchema()
)
   ....
   $this->addFieldMapping('field_foo', 'field_foo');
```

and in my columns

```
$columns = array(
      ....
      11 => array('field_foo', 'field_foo'),
     ....
    );
    return $columns;
```

The others fields are ok, but I Don't understand why with this field I get the error `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'map.sourceid8' in 'where clause'`

Answer (score 0):

MigrateSQLMap is a class that creates a table to map source identifiers to destination identifiers (2nd and 3n arguments).

```
  array(
    ....
    'field_foo' => array(
      'type' => 'varchar',
      'length' => 255,
      'not null' => FALSE,
      'description' => 'field_foo',
    )
  ),
```

Thus, you do not need that many lines in here, it's just for mapping source ids, so you can put only one column, that you know will only have unique values.

Comment: Now it's more clear. In This array I have to insert only the unique value ? If iI have 4 unique value for my Content Type, I have to insert 4 elements?

Comment: You need to put unique value(s) that will represent a single record (e.g., the row number, or a unique title, or a couple nid/vid or anything else, depending on your usecase).